# Jenkins unable to detect scenarios

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, cucumber

I have setup multiple jobs in Jenkins, each running a set of scenarios with a particular set of tags.

I am running them using top-level Maven target with the following Goals and parameters:

```
clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @RunThis"
```

This was running fine two weeks ago, but today when I reran the job no scenarios were getting executed.

Below is the code in FeatureRunner.java

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CcucumberOptions(
    monochrome = true,
    dryRun = false,
    junit = {"--allow-started-ignored"},
    plugin = {"pretty"},
    features = "src/test/java/test/features/",
    tags = "@RunThis",
    glue = {"test/testUtils", "test/steps", "src/test/java/test/steps", "resources", "testUtils"}
)
public class FeatureRunner {
}
```

I have named scenarios in the below format:

```
@RunThis
Scenario Outline: <identifier> - <testcaseName>
  When ...
  And ...
  Then ...

  Examples:
  | identifier | testcaseName          | ...
  | Test ID 1  | Sample test case name | ...
```

I'm getting the below message in build logs:

```
---------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
---------------------------------------------------
Results : 

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Well, maybe ask yourself, "what changed" since it worked? Try turning on verbose ("-X") and see if that tells you anything. Have you looked "up" tbe logs and compared to a successful run?

Comment: I've gone through the changes but couldn't find the cause. I'll try verbose. Yeah, I compared, nothing that can help me.